# Lockdown user access to directory in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

Hi we are looking into using a AAD as identity provider for a B2B SaaS application.

As not all future users of the application will have a Office 365/AAD account and tenant, we are looking into creating it as a SingleTeant application and provision users in a internal directory for this purpose (user1@ourappdir.onmicrosoft.com and so on).

However as far as i can figure this will allow any user to get a list of all other users, using the graph api for example.

Can i lock this down in any way, so a user will only be able to see info about him/her self and not anything else, no matter how they try. (Portal, graphApi, powershell...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, if you use a user account in the `Directory role` as `User` to generate the access token, and request the resource in graph, then this token only has the permission for the user himself.

There are two possible cases, allowing you to see all user profiles from graph.

1. You [called Microsoft Graph in a service or daemon app](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only)
2. The user account you used to generate the token is in the role of `administrator` in your tenant.
   [image]

You can try to use a user account in `User` role to continue the test. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal for how to assign a user role.